# GoCD - How to copy files across machines/pipelines

Tags: go-cd

I have two pipelines running on different agents, one to make a build and run unit tests another to deploy the artifacts to tomcat. The first pipeline is configured to store the artifacts, the files are copied to server/artifacts/pipelines/xx folder. How to get the second pipeline to copy the file on the second agent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Juhi said in previous answer you can make build pipeline upstream dependency for deploy pipeline. When you create deploy pipeline be sure to select in **Step 2: Materials** Pipeline as material and select build pipeline.

Since Go CD has client server architecture, all artifacts defined in one pipeline are transferred to server and available to all downstream dependencies. This happens since you can have multiple agents and there is no guarantee same agent will do both build and deploy.

In downstream pipeline (deploy pipeline in your case) you can add job with **Fetch Task** where you can select build pipeline, stage and job which created artifact and give it path to your artifact.

You can even create template out of deploy and use it for deploy on different environments.

Comment: I had seen the fetch task in the documentation .. but could not find it in the job/task screens .. it appeared after installing a different plugin (fetch from s3).

Answer (score 1):

You can create pipeline dependency between the first and second pipeline. Refer [create pipeline dependncy](http://www.go.cd/documentation/user/current/configuration/managing_dependencies.html#creating-a-dependency) document. After that [setup fetch artifact task](http://www.go.cd/documentation/user/current/configuration/managing_dependencies.html#fetching-artifacts-from-an-upstream-pipeline) in the second pipeline to fetch artifacts from the first pipeline.

Comment: both your links are broken :(

Comment: The new links should be https://docs.gocd.org/current/configuration/managing_dependencies.html#fetching-artifacts-from-an-upstream-pipeline and https://docs.gocd.org/current/configuration/managing_dependencies.html#creating-a-dependency